# $\begin{array}{}(f,\ d)=1\\(f',d')=1\end{array},\ \dfrac{f}d=\dfrac{f'}{d'} \Rightarrow\begin{align}f=f'\\d=d'\end{align}\ $ [Unique Fractionization]

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that if $fd'=f'd $ and the pair $f, d $ are coprime, that is gcd($d,f $)=1, as is the pair $f',d' $, then $f=f' $ and $d=d' $.

This should be simple, but I couldn't verify it.
Thanks in advance!

$\begin{array}{}(f,\ d)=1\\(f',d')=1\end{array},\ \dfrac{f}d=\dfrac{f'}{d'} \Rightarrow\begin{align}f=f'\\d=d'\end{align}\ $ [Unique Fractionization]

$\begin{array}{}(f,\ d)=\!1\\ \!(f',d')\!=\!1\end{array},\,\ \dfrac{f}d=\dfrac{f'}{d'}\ \Rightarrow\,\begin{align} f=f'\\d=d'\end{align}\ $ [Unique Fractionization]

Comment: Are $f$ and $f'$ related in any way? What about $g$ and $g'$? If not, then I suggest for clarity not to use apostrophes to denote different variables.

Comment: You need to assume all are positive else it is false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

Use the [Euclid's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) to show that $f$ divides $f'$ and $f'$ divides $f$ and conclude that $f=f'$ and then $d=d'$.

Comment: Hi, I need help here. I tried as follows: if $a|f $ then $fd' =aqd'=f'd$. And so $a |f'd $ but $a $ cannot divide $f' $ so that we must have $a |d $, and $aqd'=f'ak $ so that $qd'=f'k $. But I get no where here...

Comment: We have $f|f'd$ and $\gcd(f,d)=1$ so by the Euclid's lemma we have $f|f'$. Do the same thing to find $f'|f$.

Comment: Understod how to do it now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Said in fractions $\ \begin{array}{c} (f,\,\ d)=\!1\\ (f',d')\!=\!1\end{array},\, \ \ \dfrac{f}d\, =\, \dfrac{f'}{d'}\ \Rightarrow\,\ \begin{array}{c} f\, =\, f'\\ d\, =\, d'\end{array}\,\  $  $ \bbox[5px,border:1px solid #c00]{\begin{align}&\bf{Unique\ Fractionization}\\ &\!\text{ reduced fractions are }\textit{unique}\end{align}}$

**Proof** $ $ It suffices to show the denominator of a reduced fraction $\rm\color{#0a0}{divides}$ every other denominator, since then we deduce that $\,d\mid d'$ and $\,d'\mid d,\ $ so $\,d = d',\,$ both being positive (cf. [my comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/825667/show-that-if-fd-fd-and-the-pairs-f-d-and-f-d-are-coprime-then-f#comment1706073_825667)).

Now if $\ \color{#c00}{(a,b)= 1}\ \,$ & $\,\ \dfrac{A}B\, =\, \dfrac{a}b\, $ then $\, Ab = aB \ $ so $\ \color{#c00}{b\mid a}B\,\Rightarrow\,\color{#0a0}{b\mid B}\ $ by [Euclid's Lemma.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/252748/242)

**Remark** $\,\ $ Further:  $\ \  \bbox[5px,border:1px solid #c00]{\begin{align} A &\,=\, n\:\!a\\ B &\,=\, n\:\! b\end{align}\ }\ \,$   by $\,\ \dfrac{A}a = \color{#0a0}{\dfrac{B}b} =: n\in\Bbb Z$

By  $\,n\mid A,B,\:$ if $\ (A,B)=1\,$ then $\, n\mid 1\,$ so $\, n= \pm 1,\,$ i.e. *reduced fractions are unique up to sign*. Usually we normalize fractions by requiring *positive* denominators, cf. [unit normalization](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2939562/242).

Conversely, this denominator divisibility property implies Euclid's Lemma (reverse above proof). Thus both are equivalent. Further, they are both equivalent to uniqueness of prime factorizations. As such, I call the fractional version **unique fractionization**. It is discussed further in [various answers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user:242%20%22unique%20fractionization%22) If you know about ideals, then you may also find of interest [various posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A242+%22denominator+ideal%22) on **denominator ideals** (the denominator divisibility property is a special case of the fact that the set of denominators of a fraction forms an ideal, and $\,\Bbb Z\,$ is a PID, i.e. all ideals are *principal*, being generated by their least nonzero element). So reduced fraction uniqueness boils down to the *principality* of an ideal.

**Alternatively**, we can replace use of Euclid's Lemma by a descent using the Division Algorithm, which yields a more direct (but less conceptual proof), e.g. [see here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/714313/242). This can be employed to give proofs of irrationality of square-roots using only the division algorithm, using a descent achieved by taking fractional parts of fractions, e.g. see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/16544/242) (based on a discussion with John Conway on irrationality proofs).

**More generally** see [Euler's Four Number Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3835192/242) for the non-coprime case.

Comment: The trivial case $\,dd' = 0\,$ is left to the reader.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, using
Corollary 31.4 from CLRS:

For all integers a and b and any nonnegative integer n,
$ (an, bn) = n*(a, b); $

$ (f, d) = 1 => (ff', df') = f' $ (multiplying by f')

$ (f', d') = 1 => (ff', d'f) = f $ (multiplying by f)

Now it's easy:

$ (ff', df') = (ff', d'f) => f' = f $ (because df' = d'f)

$ df' = df = d'f => d' = d $