# Trouble with elementary consequences of relatively prime relation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was working through a proof that came to a result concerning relatively prime integers (the full proof is fairly long, proving that $\mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_q\cong \mathbb{Z}_{pq} \Leftrightarrow p,q $  coprime) giving

> Let $p$ and $q$ coprime, $n=rp=tq$ gives $$\frac{r}{t}=\frac{q}{p}$$ And since $p,q$ coprime then $r=q$ and $t=p$. Then going on to say $n=pq....$ etc

I just can't get my head around this statement; we can just let $r=2, t=4$ and $q=1, p=2$ and this satisfies all the conditions and doesn't give $r=q$ and $t=p$.

EDIT: SOLVED. See comments below. Thanks

Comment: Generally you need to assume $\,r,t\,$ coprime to make that deduction. This is the uniqueness of reduced fractions ("unique fractionization"), e.g. [see here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/825871/242). And unless you normalize signs you get only $\,|p| = |t|\,$ etc.

Comment: Sorry just worked it out, forgot to include that $n$ is the order of the element $(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_q$ and $a^{p}=e_1$ and $b^q=e_2$. Therefore $n$ is effectively the lowest common multiple of $p,q$. Hence as $p,q$ coprime we have $n=pq$