# Simple Linear Diophantine Equation - problem with proof.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I'm reading up on diophantine equations and one of the theorems is that

> "if $x,y$ is **any** solution of $ax + by = c$, then it is of the form $x_0 +\dfrac{b}{d}t ,\, y_0 - \dfrac{a}{d}t$ where $d = \gcd(a,b)$"

(Where $(x_0, y_0)$ is a particular solution.)

They subtract the two equations, then divide by d to give $\dfrac{a}{d}(x-x_0) + \dfrac{b}{d}(y-y_0) = 0$

Then they claim that $\dfrac{b}{d}$ must divide $x-x_0$ but I don't understand why, could someone please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a'=\frac{a}{d}$ and $b'=\frac{b}{d}$. Then $a'(x-x_0)+b'(y-y_0)=0$. This can be rewritten as
$$b'(y_0-y)=a'(x-x_0).\tag{1}$$
Since $d=\gcd(a,b)$, the numbers $a'$ and $b'$ are relatively prime. From (1) we can see that $b'$ divides $a'(x-x_0)$. Since $\gcd(b',a')=1$, it follows that $b'$ divides $x-x_0$.

Comment: Oh Thanks! now I get the relatively prime bit, since they're both divided by the gcd.

Comment: @MarkK This can e viewed a bit more conceptually as [unique fractionization](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/825871/242), and the first part is a special case of the fact that fact that the [general solution of an (affine) linear equation](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a242%20particular%20homogeneous) is the sum of any particular solution plus the general solution of the associated homogeneous equation

Comment: @MarkK: You are welcome.