# For integers $a, b>1$ such that $a$ divides $b^2,$ alternative proof that $a$ and $b$ have common divisors?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a question as follow:

Suppose I have two positive integers $a, b$ (both not equal to $1$) such that $a$ divides $b^2.$ Show that $a$ and $b$ have common divisors.

It is straightforward to use prime factorisation to prove. However, I am seeking for alternative explanation.

Comment: You can use that there are integers $x,y$ with $xa + yb = \gcd(a,b)$.

Comment: Here is my attempt using your hint: Suppose the $gcd(a,b)=1$. With $xa+yb=1$, we have $xab+yb^2=b$. Since $a|b^2$, $b^2=ka$ for some integer $k$. Therefore, $xab+yka=b$ which means $a(xb+yk)=b$ which means $a|b$. This means $a|gcd(a,b)=1$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: That's one way to use it. Another is to note that $a \mid (xa + yb)^2$, so $a \mid \gcd(a,b)^2$, whence $\gcd(a,b) \geqslant \sqrt{a} > 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of $$a|b^2$$ there is a positive integer $k$ with $$ak=b^2$$ Hence, we have $$\frac{k}{b}=\frac{b}{a}$$

If we assume $gcd(a,b)=1$, we can conclude $a|b$ because every fraction equal to $\frac{b}{a}$ is of the form $\frac{mb}{ma}$, hence $ma=b$ for some $m$.

Hence $a\ne 1$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$. This is a contradiction to $gcd(a,b)=1$, hence $gcd(a,b)>1$ completing the proof.

Comment: Thank you for your proof. In fact, if $gcd(a,b)=1$, from $\frac{k}{b}=\frac{b}{a}$, either $a|b$ or $b|a$. Either way, one of them is a divisor of the other, which is a contradiction to $gcd(a,b)=1$.

Comment: @Nov For more on this and related properties [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/825871/242) and [many other posts on **unique fractionization**](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a242%20unique%20%22fractionization%22)  (my name for this property of fractions, which is essentially equivalent to Euclid's Lemma).

Comment: @Bill Dubuque Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a,b$ be two coprime integers such that $a\mid b^2.$ By [Gauss's generalization of Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma#Formulations) (used twice), $a\mid1.$

Answer (score 1):

If $\gcd(a,b)=1,$ then $\exists m,n\in \Bbb Z$ such that $ma+nb=1$ which implies that
$mab+nb^2=b \tag1$
Since $a|b^2$, $a$ divides the left hand side of the equation $(1)$.
Hence, $a|b$ and $\gcd(a,b)=a=1$.

Comment: This is the best answer posted to date. I would have concluded a bit more fully: Having established $a\mid b$, it is the case that $(a\mid b) \land (\gcd(a,b)=1) \Rightarrow a=1$. But the problem specifies $a,b>1$. Therefore the starting assumption in the proof that $\gcd(a,b)=1$ is false, whence $\gcd(a,b)>1$, which is what OP particularly asks for.

Comment: This is a usual proof of [Gauss's generalization of Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma#Formulations) in a particular case. Note that this generalization actually does not need Bézout identity. It can be proved directly in any [GCD domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCD_domain).