# Is the following proof that $\sqrt2$ is irrational valid?

Tags: proof-verification

Given that all rational numbers have the following property: $\displaystyle\left\{ \frac{x}{y} \,\middle|\, x,y\in\mathbb Z\right\}$

it can be inferred therefore that $$\sqrt2=\frac{x}{y}$$ therefore $$2=\frac{x^2}{y^2}$$ and since $2=\frac{2}{1}$, it can be inferred that $y^2=1$, hence $$2=x^2$$ and $$\sqrt2=x$$ hence, by contradiction to $\displaystyle \sqrt2=\frac{x}{y}$, the original statement is false and $\sqrt2$ is in fact an irrational number.

Comment: You have to assume that $x$ and $y$ are coprime to conclude $y^2=1$.

Comment: You also haven't stated specifically why $x=\sqrt 2$ is a contradiction - what does it contradict.

Comment: Without saying how "it can be inferred that..." the proof is incomplete (and possibly incorrect). It is impossible to judge its correctness without knowing the crucial missing step(s).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is wrong. For instance, from the equality $\frac21=\frac{x^2}{y^2}$, you deduce that $2=x^2$ and that $1=y^2$. Why? What about the equality $\frac1{\sqrt2}=\frac{\sqrt2}2$ (which is valid)? Do you deduce from it that $1=\sqrt2$?

Comment: Technically it is *incomplete* not wrong, since we don't know what the OP has in mind for "it can be inferred that..." (which could possibly be correct).

Comment: In the immortal words of Miss Eliza Doolittle: “Not bloody likely!”. Besides, the OP marked my answer as the accepted one.

Comment: In fact it is not too unlikely, as I have seen that occur many times before in arguments like this.  And a checkmark on a random website has absolutely nothing to do with mathematical definitions.

Comment: @BillDubuque The sentence "From $\frac{x^2}{y^2}=\frac21$, we can inferr that $2=x^2$ and $1=y^2$" is not an "incomplete" statement, it is a false statement. We cannot infer one from the other. This is not up for debate no matter what OP has in mind.

Comment: @5xum You can't possibly judge the OP's (omitted) argument as false without knowing precisely what it is (since there are valid ways to complete it).

Comment: @BillDubuque There is no valid proof that proves that $$\frac{x^2}{y^2} = \frac21 \implies x^2=2, y^2=1$$ is a true statement.

Comment: @5xum But that's not what the OP wrote. Rather, the OP's "it can be inferred that" could well mean: wlog the rational $x/y$ is reduced so by Euclid/FTA $\,x^2/y^2$ is also reduced so $\,x^2/y^2 = 2/1\,\Rightarrow\,x^2 = 2, y^2 = 1\,$ by uniqueness of reduced fractions [(Unique Fractionization)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/825871/242). That's an argument that many beginners have intuitively in mind, but often don't have the experience to *complete* to a  rigorous proof.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is incorrect here:

> it can be inferred therefore that $$\sqrt2=\frac{x}{y}$$ therefore $$2=\frac{x^2}{y^2}$$ and since $2=\frac{2}{1}$ it can be inferred that $y^2=1$,

This is incorrect. For example, if we set $a=8,b=4$, then $\frac{a}{b}=2$, however 
we cannot, from $2=\frac 21$,conclude that $b=1$.

---

Furthermore, you only conclude that $x=\sqrt{2}$, and then claim "this is a contradiction", but it is not clear why this is a contradiction.

Comment: As I remarked in Jose's answer, the proof is *incomplete, not *incorrect*, since there are valid ways that "it can be inferred that ..."