# Proof that the nth root of a rational s/t is irrational unless s and t are perfect nth powers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers

I'm trying to prove that $\sqrt[n]{\frac{s}{t}}$ is irrational unless both s and t are perfect nth powers. I have found plenty of proofs for nth root of an integer but cannot find anything for rationals. Also trying to work up from the proofs I have found is rather difficult.

My lecturer wants me to prove this using uniqueness of prime factorisation but I also have no idea where to start with that.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: $\large{\sqrt[n]{\frac{s}{t}}=\frac{\sqrt[n]{s}}{\sqrt[n]{t}}}$ and use proofs for root of integer?

Comment: Hmm yeah I think that would work, I will have to double check with my lecturer but it is a starting point at the very least

Comment: Where are you stuck? It's straightforward using prime factroizations - just like the case $\,t = 1.\ \ $

Comment: For this to be true, one has to stipulate that $s$ and $t$ have no common factors. (Except $\pm1$!) Strictly speaking, it is false as stated. For instance, $\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{2}}$ is rational, but $2$ is not a perfect square.

Comment: I'm just stuck with all of it to be honest, not sure where to start or where to end really.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To build off Vasya and Calum's helpful comments:

Let $\frac{s}{t}$ be an irreducible fraction (to address Vasya's comment).

Continuing with the main proof, recall Vasya's comment:

> $\sqrt[n]{\frac{s}{t}} = \frac{\sqrt[n]{s}}{\sqrt[n]{t}}$

We will quickly prove this.

Obviously $(\sqrt[n]{\frac{s}{t}})^n = \frac{s}{t}.$

Notice $\frac{s}{t} = \frac{(\sqrt[n]{s})^n}{(\sqrt[n]{t})^n} = (\frac{\sqrt[n]{s}}{\sqrt[n]{t}})^n.$

It follows that $\sqrt[n]{\frac{s}{t}} = \frac{\sqrt[n]{s}}{\sqrt[n]{t}}$ since the $n$th root is either a bijection or always positive.

Without loss of generality, let $s$ have a prime factorization $p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}...p_i^{a_i}.$ Let $\sqrt[n]{s}$ be an integer with prime factorization $q_1^{b_1}q_2^{b_2}...q_j^{b_j}.$

Clearly $p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}...p_i^{a_i} = q_1^{nb_1}q_2^{nb_2}...q_j^{nb_j}.$
We know the prime factorization of $s$ is unique, so we know that each power of $p$ corresponds to *some* power of $q.$
It's not clear which $p$ corresponds to which $q,$ but it is clear that all the prime factors are $n$th powers.

Comment: Erm, has part of your comment been chopped off. it looks like the comment has stopped just as you got to the proof

Comment: Sorry, yeah, I submitted this by mistake as I closed my computer. My bad. :(

Comment: Would you be able to finish what you were saying. Looks like it was gonna be really useful

Comment: Fixed! Sorry about that. I was in class. :p

Comment: Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Remember to upvote if my post was helpful!

Comment: -1 (a) What is "this qualification"? (b) Why mention $\gcd(s, t)$ being an $n$th power? (c) When you say $\gcd(s, t)$ is $0$, you mean it's $1$. (d) The $n$th root can't be a "bijection". On the other hand, the $n$th root *function* on $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ *is* bijective, *and* its values are all positive - there is no "or". (e) Why "without loss of generality"? (f) You can't *let* $\sqrt[n]{s}$ be an integer. You can't even assume it. It is part of what has to be proved. (g) if you already (somehow) have that $\sqrt[n]{s}$ is an integer, then it's too late to use prime factorisation to prove it!

Comment: I could go on... But apart from (a) to (g) (and other points I could criticise if I weren't now exhausted!), I just find it impossible to follow the overall logic of your argument, in spite of *many* rereadings. I'm sorry to downvote your answer, especially as you're a new poster; but I see so many things wrong that it seems impossible to fix it even with extensive editing. If it turns out that I have simply failed to understand  what should have been clear, perhaps I can cancel my vote, or others will upvote to compensate. Anyway, your answer has been accepted, which I suppose encourages you!

Comment: a) 'This qualification' is that $\frac{s}{t}$ is in lowest terms. That's true iff $gcd(s,t) = 0.$ I added that to address Vasya's comment. b) Good point! c) You're right! d) When n is odd, the nth root and the nth root function are equivalent. When n is even, the nth root function is defined to choose the positive root. e) The same argument must be applied to t in exactly the same way, but there is no difference between the arguments, so I only did it for s.

Comment: f) $\sqrt[n]{\frac{s}{t}}$ is rational iff $\sqrt[n]{s}$ is an integer. If it is an integer, it has a prime factorization. If you raise that prime factorization to the nth power, you will get a prime factorization of s made entirely of nth powers. That prime factorization is unique, concluding the proof. I'm not sure what's confusing about this.

Comment: I'm flattered you bothered to reread my answer so many times, and sorry that you didn't like it. Thanks for pointing out that silly error with gcd(s,t) (I feel a little dumb, hehe).

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment than an answer, because it doesn't use the uniqueness of prime factorisation. Instead, it uses the more basic result that if a positive integer $c$ divides the product of two positive integers $a$ and $b$, and $b$ and $c$ are relatively prime, i.e. they have no common factors other than $\pm1$, then $c$ divides $a$.

Suppose that the fraction $\tfrac{s}{t}$ is in its lowest terms, i.e. $s$ and $t$ are relatively prime; and suppose that $\left(\tfrac{u}{v}\right)^n = \tfrac{s}{t}$, where $\tfrac{u}{v}$ also is in its lowest terms, i.e. $u$ and $v$ are relatively prime. Then:
\begin{equation}
\tag{$*$}\label{eq:simple}
tu^n = sv^n.
\end{equation}

The hypothesis that $u$ and $v$ are relatively prime implies that $u^n$ and $v^n$ are also relatively prime:

*Proof.* Suppose that an integer $r > 1$ divides both $u^n$ and $v^n$. Every integer $> 1$ has a prime factor. (This fact is admittedly an ingredient of the proof of uniqueness of prime factorisation, but still, it is a simpler theorem.) Let $p$ be a prime factor of $r$. By the hypothesis that $u$ and $v$ are relatively prime, $p$ cannot divide both $u$ and $v$. But if $p$ does not divide $u$, then by repeated application of the theorem quoted above, $p$ does not divide $u^n$. Similarly, if $p$ does not divide $v$, then $p$ does not divide $v^n$. Therefore, $p$ does not divide both $u^n$ and $v^n$. This contradicts the hypothesis that $p$ divides $r$. Therefore, no such $p$ and no such $r$ can exist. $\square$

Now, four applications of our favourite theorem to \eqref{eq:simple} show that $s$ divides $u^n$, $u^n$ divides $s$, $t$ divides $v^n$, and $v^n$ divides $t$. Therefore, $s = u^n$ and $t = v^n$. $\square$

(Perhaps in an effort to be simple, this has ended up being too laborious? Oh, well.)

Comment: Or, to put it another and better way (taking inspiration from an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1345466/213690) by Yves Daoust, and slightly generalising it): the two equal fractions $\tfrac{u^n}{v^n}$ and $\tfrac{s}{t}$ are both in their lowest terms, therefore they are identical.

Comment: The **uniqueness of reduced fractions** is actually [proved here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/825871/242), but not in the prior linked post by Yves.