# Relation $ab=cd$ in $\mathbb{Z}$(UFD) with $a$ and $c$ coprime.

Tags: unique-factorization-domains, coprime

Why if $15x=-19y$ where $x$ and $y$ are integers, this means that there is an integer t such that x=-19t and y=15t. I think it has something to do with the fact that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a UFD, but I can't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

You have *Gauß'lemma* (generalisation of *Euclid's lemma*):

> If an integer $a$ divides $bc$ ($b,c\in\mathbf Z$) ans if $a$ and $b$ are coprime, then $a$ divides $c$.

Naturally, this is valid in any U.F.D.

Answer (score 1):

You have $$15x =- 19y$$ where $x$ and $y$ are integers.

Well since $15|15x$ it has to divide $-19y$ and since $15$ and $-19$ are relatively prime, $15$ has to divide $y$.

That is $y=15t$

Now if you plug $y=15t$ in your original equation and divide both sides by $15$ you will find that $x=-19t$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, discarding the trivial case $\,x =0\iff y=0\,$ we can write it fractionally as

$$\dfrac{x}y = \dfrac{-19\ \ }{15}\iff \begin{align} &x = -9n\\ &y =\  15n\end{align}\ \ \text{ for some integer } n$$

This property - well known since grade school - remains true if we replace $-19/15\,$ by any other irreducible fraction. A proof follows easily from existence and uniqueness or prime factorizations (UFD) or closely related results such as Euclid's Lemma, Four Number Theorem, etc. It is sometimes called *unique fractionization*. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/825871/242) for further discussion.